# Angular JS Validation of complex ASP.NET MVC object

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to validate my model within a subform using AngularJS, but the error message isn't showing up, and the button is always disabled.

```html
<form novalidate>

    ... Some other form fields

    <ng-form name="SearchPostcodeForm">
        <div class="partial-search-postcode-service form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label
                    class="control-label col-md-2"
                    for="CustomerAddressDetails_CurrentAddress_SearchPostcode">
                    Post code
                </label>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-10">
                    <input
                        id="CustomerAddressDetails_CurrentAddress_SearchPostcode"
                        name="CustomerAddressDetails.CurrentAddress.SearchPostcode"
                        ng-model="CustomerAddress.CurrentAddress.SearchPostcode"
                        required="required" type="text" >
                    <small ng-show="SearchPostcodeForm.CustomerAddress_CurrentAddress_SearchPostcode.$error.required">
                        Your postcode is required.
                    </small>
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Find your address"
                name="action:Current_SearchPostcode"
                data-val-valgroup-name="SearchPostcode"
                class="btn btn-primary causesvalidation"
                ng-click="seachPostcode($event, 'Current');"
                ng-disabled="SearchPostcodeForm.$invalid"
                disabled="disabled">
        </div>
    </ng-form>

    ... Some other form fields

</form>
```

Modifying values in the SearchPostCode does update classes, so the validation itself appears to be happening.

For example:

```
<ng-form name="SearchPostcodeForm" novalidate="" class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required">
```

Becomes:

```
<ng-form name="SearchPostcodeForm" novalidate="" class="ng-dirty ng-valid ng-valid-required">
```

But the error message never gets displayed, and the button never enabled.

What am I missing here?  Is this a problem with the really long names for the form field?  Or should I be using the id?  (where the '.' separators may be causing the problem?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After re-reading it here... I'm already pointing at the id instead of the name (which is wrong, obviously).

Furthermore, because my form name has the '.' separators in it, I needed to access it slightly differently.

```
<small
    ng-show="SearchPostcodeForm['CustomerAddressDetails.CurrentAddress.SearchPostcode'].$error.required">
    Your postcode is required.
</small>
```

Working example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/cgUlYEGubYcfDh80YqsI

Now everything is working as it should.